# I keep getting traceback and str callback errors after so much troubleshooting and I can't seem to fix it. Python contacts book

Tags: python

i have saved the dictionary in a separeate document with all the correct syntax called directory.txt. The code is for a contacts book/directory using dictionaries. I'm not sure wheter im supposed to define functions before or after calling them but i've tried both and it still doesnt seem to work.

```
file = open("directory.txt","r+")
contacts = file.read()
def new():
    print("Please enter the name of the new contact.")
    name = input()
    print("Please enter the number of the new contact.")
    num = input()
    contacts.update({name:num})
    print("Contact has successfully been added.")
def view():
    for keys, values in contacts():
        print("\n*************************************************")
        print("Name:",keys)
        print("Number:",values)
        print("*************************************************\n")
def edit():
    for keys, values in contacts():
        print("\n*************************************************")
        print("Name:",keys)
        print("Number:",values)
        print("*************************************************\n")
    print("Type the name of the contact you would like to edit.")
    global name_two
    name_two = input()
    print("If you would like to edit the number, type 'number'.\nIf you would like to edit the name, type 'name'.\nIf you would like to delete this contact, type 'delete'.")
    edit = input().lower()
    if edit == "number":
        num_edit()
    elif edit == "name":
        name_edit()
    elif edit == "delete":
        delete()
def num_edit():
    print("What would you like to change the number to?")
    num_two = input()
    contacts[name_two] = num_two
    print("Contact successfully changed.")
def name_edit():
    num_save = contacts[name_two]
    del contacts[name_two]
    print("Enter the new name for the contact.")
    name_new = input()
    contacts.update({name_new:num_save})
    print("Contact successfully changed.")
def delete():
    del contacts[name_two]
    print("Contact successfully deleted.")

print("Welcome to the Contacts Book.")
print("*****************************\n")
print("If you would like to make a new contact, type 'new'.\nIf you would like to view your contacts, type 'view'.\n If you would like to edit your contacts, type 'edit'.\nIf you would like to exit, type 'exit'")
mode = input().lower()
if mode == "new":
    new()
elif mode == "view":
    view()
elif mode == "edit":
    edit()
else:
    print("Goodbye.")
```

Here is the error message when i type 'view' as the first input:

```
File "c:\Users\brain\Downloads\contacts.py", line 56, in <module>
    view()
  File "c:\Users\brain\Downloads\contacts.py", line 11, in view
    for keys, values in contacts():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you also post the error message?

Comment: yup just added it

Comment: Even if `contacts` were a `dict`, `for keys, values in contacts()` would be wrong, because you're treating it as a `function`; you probably meant `for keys, values in contacts.values()`.
But at the beginning you do `contacts = file.read()`, so now it is a `string`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just have an unnecessary set of parenthesis after contacts (it's a var not a function as far as I can see), so just remove those and you should be good. EDIT: gimix reply is far more accurate than what I wrote here

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some variable named **str** in your code and that caused this problem. This is called **shadowing the built** in functions, you can try to find that variable with a search in your project file and change it to some other name and should solve it.